# How to set "v-on" on content added with "v-html" in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible in Vue to add `v-on` events on strings added in `v-html`?
In the example, when clicking the 'Maggie' link nothing happens. It doesn't seem to be registered with Vue.

Or maybe there's another way to do it?
I'm using Vue.js 2.1.3

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            users: ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', '<a href="#" v-on:click="click_user">Maggie</a>']
        },
        methods: {
            click_user: function() {
                console.log('Click user')
            },
        }
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="user in users" v-html="user"></div><br>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="click_user">This works.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try to create a component and pass as prop the `user` var. Use v-html for that porpouse it seem to be a bad practice

Answer (score 4):

From the vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html):

> Updates the element’s innerHTML. Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates. If you find yourself trying to compose templates using v-html, try to rethink the solution by using components instead.

This means that `v-on` will not work within `v-html` , because it requires vue to work.

---

### Potential Solution to Your Specific Problem

Conditionally render a link using `v-if`, otherwise render plain text.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [
      { name: 'Homer', clickable: false },
      { name: 'Marge', clickable: false },
      { name: 'Bart', clickable: false },
      { name: 'Lisa', clickable: false },
      { name: 'Maggie', clickable: true },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    click_user: function() {
      console.log('Click user')
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="user in users">
    <div v-if="!user.clickable">{{user.name}}</div>
    <a v-if="user.clickable" href="#" v-on:click="click_user">{{user.name}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rendering `<a href="#" v-on:click="click_user">Maggie</a>` with `v-html` will not bind any click event. You can read more about it in [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML). It will just render `v-on:click` as attribute.

Keep simple array of data. I don't think you need `v-html`. Use either `text` or `index` with `if`(one or two) or `switch`(for multiple) condition for triggering event.

```
window.onload = function() {
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            users: ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie']
        },
        methods: {
            click_user: function(text) {
              if(text=='Maggie') console.log('Click user')
            }
        }
    })
}

<div id="app">
   <div v-for="user in users" v-on:click="click_user(user)">{{user.name}}</div><br>    
</div>
```

Or

```
window.onload = function() {
  new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
          users: ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie']
      },
      methods: {
        click_user: function(index) {
          if(index==4) console.log('Click user')
        }
      }
   })
}

<div id="app">
   <div v-for="user,index in users" v-on:click="click_user(index)">{{user.name}}</div><br>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a component and pass as prop the user var. 
Here is an example of what you can do.

`<users-list v-for="user in users" v-bind:user="user"></users-list>`

Here is a quick functional example: https://jsfiddle.net/leocoder/tor13m26/1/

Use v-html for that purpose it seem to be a bad practice.